# Pass values between TestNG tests

Tags: java, testing, testng

Background: I'm executing tests with TestNG and I have a class annotated with @Test that generates a number, or ID if you will, and that same number is the input value of my second test. Is it possible to pass values between TestNG tests?

Comment: Tests should be standalone, so this seems like bad practice to me. If you post your code, it would be easier to help.

Comment: The test case is end-to-end, so i wanna trace the case number I created in the first test case all the way to closure.

Comment: You would have to do the handling yourself - create a variable to be used across tests.  If you are running parallely, make sure you handle this  by using threadlocal to put your variable in.

Answer (score 1):

Bad practice or not, it can be accomplished by simply using class fields. Just make sure your cases are executed in predictable order (eg. using @Test(priority) or dependsOn TestNG feature).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. For example if you have two tests that is related you can pass the values from one test to another via test context attributes:

```
@Test
public void test1(ITestContext context) { //Will be injected by testNG
    /* Do the test here */
    context.setAttribute("myOwnAttribute", "someTestResult");
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
public void test2(ITestContext context) { //Will be injected by testNG
    String prevResult = (String) context.getAttribute("myOwnAttribute");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create one test that handles whole case. Tests can't depend on each other, it's considered as bad practise. If you are using maven order of tests execution can be different in different environments.